# Python Paramiko- Have stdin duplicate pointing to stdout so it can be seen in output

Tags: python, logging, stream, stdout, stdin

I am writing a python script with the paramiko module. It ssh's into a remote hosts, runs script, and automates/answers interactive prompts. It works pretty good so far. For the output, I would like to have both stdin, stdout, stderr streams pointing together(to stdout) so I can see them in stdout.readlines(). But as it is now, I am not seeing the stdin.write() calls I placed in the script. How can I get stdin.write() included in the output?

```
import paramiko

bar = "5555"
foofilename = ""
cont = "Y"
fname = '/foobar/file.txt'

ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect( host, port=22, username=uname, password=pword)

stdin, stdout, stderr=ssh.exec_command("script.sh")
stdin.write(bar+"\n")
stdin.flush()
stdin.write(foofilename+"\n")
stdin.flush()
stdin.write(cont+"\n")
stdin.flush()
stdin.write(fname+"\n")

stdin.flush()
output =  stdout.readlines()
for line in output:
    print line.split("\n")
```